# How does the basic nodejs server setup code works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm studying node.js currently, and want to make sure my understanding of the code down below. The code is about setting up a server using only node.js.

```js
const http = require('http');

// create the server
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // check request from a client
  if (req.url === '/') {
    // response to the client
    res.end('welcome to my home page');
  } else {
    res.end(`<h1>Page Not Found</h1>`);
  }
});

// start the server
server.listen(5000, () => console.log('server listening on port 5000'));
```

1. "createServer()" callback is registered
2. "listen()" callback is registered
3. "createServer()" runs - Server created
4. "listen()" runs - Server started

- Server runs on a event loop until I/user exits.

5. When there is a request (ex) page reload), "createServer()" runs.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I fixed that. btw, why am I getting a downvote? Any chance you would know?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting the downvote.  Perhaps because it's not a classic problem that we can easily write a meaningful answer for.  Instead, you're asking "is this right" which isn't usually how questions work here.  I don't have any  problem with it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your explanation is not quite how it works.  Here's a bit more detailed summary of how the code works.

1. `http.createServer(callback)` is called.
2. This creates an http server object and configures with that server object a callback to be called on each new incoming request.  The result of that function call is that it returns a `server` object.  The server is not yet running.
3. `server.listen(port, callback)` is called.
4. That starts your server so that it is now accepting incoming TCP connections on a particular port.  When the process of starting the server is complete and the server is live (which is an asynchronous process), then this callback gets called to notify you that the server is now up and running.
5. Later, when an incoming request to the server arrives, the native code behind the server will create an event for the nodejs event loop to dispatch.  When the event loops gets to that event, it will call that callback that you passed to `http.createServer(callback)` and will pass to it the request and response objects which your callback can use to respond to the incoming http request.
6. When you return from that callback, the event loop will then be able to dispatch the next event waiting to run (which could be any type of event in nodejs, another http request, timer, other networking, disk I/O, etc...).